# Will this construction bend?

Tags: pipe, metal

I'm planning to build a computer setup where it's possible to work while lying down (e.g. in bed). However, I don't know if the construction which holds the monitor will bend due to the weight of the monitor and the horizontal pipe.

The construction is rather simple. Two connected pipes in an upside down L shape, as can be seen in the attached picture. It should be possible to move the vertical pipe up and down, and the monitor left and right. The monitor is attached to a VESA mount, which is attached to the horizontal pipe.

My goal is to choose the right **material**, **diameter** and **thickness** of the pipes, such that there will be **no bending** of either the vertical, or the horizontal pipe (except for maybe a few millimeters).

**Here is what is fixed:**

- vertical pipe length (60")
- horizontal pipe length (40")
- monitor weight (8 lbs)

I never built something like that before, and I'm no expert in materials science. Also, where I live, there is no stores like home depot. The only option I have is to order online, that's why I want to make sure I buy the right pipes.

Here is what I have thought of so far.

**Vertical pipe:**

- Material -> steel
- Diameter -> 2.22"
- Thickness -> 0.15"

**Horizontal pipe:**

- Material -> aluminum (to save weight)
- Diameter -> 0.78"
- Thickness -> 0.19"

---

Will this construction work without bending of one or both pipes?

If not, what parameters do I need to change to prevent bending?

[image]

Comment: You can make this stable **without** a 110lb weight by extending feet under the bed (so it's a [ shape rather than an inverted L shape.)

Comment: Probably will work but I would just but a hospital food tray cart

Comment: Where will the *center of gravity* of this structure be? You can treat each component as a unit, for instance the weight and vertical pipe will have its CG dead center.  The horizontal pipe will have its CG halfway down its length.  The monitor and VESA mount will have their CG centered.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I want the structure to be transportable. So e.g. that I can move it to a couch or use it for working while standing. I think that a [ shape would use too much space on the floor because of the floor standing area, so it would restrict where I can put the structure. And I already have a bucket with cement ready for use as weight.

Comment: @DavidMoritz, but with a hospital food tray cart, it wouldn't be possible to lie down for looking at the monitor without tilting the head. I forgot to mention, that the VESA mount will be freely rotatable around the horizontal pipe. This way the monitor can point directly down, and I can look without moving the head while in bed.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, well I think the center of gravity of the structure as a whole will be slightly to the right where the horizontal pipe is attached to the vertical pipe. So I think that the vertical pipe might bend a little to the the right because of the weight of the horizontal pipe + monitor, and the horizontal pipe might bend down a little where the monitor is attached. I just want to make sure that the bending doesn't exceed a few millimeters.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're focused on the  bending. Everyone else is focused on the *toppling* which you have dismissed because "surely 110lb is enough".   Actually, the bending *will affect* the toppling. Because bending will move the monitor's moment arm to the right.

Comment: Have the vertical pipe stick out more than the just to the intersection, then you can cable a suspension from the top of the vertical pole to the monitor arm's end, a strong triangle under tension, thus eliminating any sag on the thin Al crossbar. What is the elbow made from? That part will be the weak point, and it's failure could break the monitor.

Comment: Add Full motion VESA mount to cart or remove carts top and its essentially a metal arm